# clang++ Error when compiling the Minko engine SDK for HTML 5

Tags: html, compilation, minko

I have followed all steps mentioned in [Compiling the SDK for HTML5](https://github.com/aerys/minko/blob/master/doc/tutorial/Compiling_the_SDK_for_HTML5.md) to compile the Minko framework to HTML5.
When I run the batch file build_html5.bat, i have this error

> 000000000000000), RtlUserThreadStart() + 0x21 bytes(s)
>
> clang++.exe: error: clang frontend command failed with exit code 255 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> ERROR    root: compiler frontend failed to generate LLVM bitcode, halting
>
> mingw32-make[1](https://github.com/aerys/minko/blob/master/doc/tutorial/Compiling_the_SDK_for_HTML5.md): *** [obj/html5/release/Picking.o] Error 1
>
> mingw32-make: *** [minko-framework] Error 2

Here is my Emscripten conf :

> LLVM_ROOT='C:/Program Files/Emscripten/clang/e1.30.0_64bit'
>
> EMSCRIPTEN_NATIVE_OPTIMIZER='C:/Program
>
> Files/Emscripten/clang/e1.30.0_64bit/optimizer.exe'
>
> NODE_JS='C:/Program Files/Emscripten/node/0.12.2_64bit/node.exe'
>
> PYTHON='C:/Program Files/Emscripten/python/2.7.5.3_64bit/python.exe'
>
> EMSCRIPTEN_ROOT='C:/Program Files/Emscripten/emscripten/1.30.0'
>
> MINGW_ROOT='C:/Program Files/Emscripten/mingw/4.6.2_32bit'
>
> JAVA='C:/Program Files/Emscripten/java/7.45_64bit/bin/java.exe'

Im on windows 7 64 bit.
Anyone know what causes this error and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem with Emscripten 1.30, it should be resolved in future versions. For the moment, stick to Emscripten 1.29.